# Accessible Scope of List< > variable

Tags: c#, list, global-variables

I have a form where I am gathering user input thru a variety of objects: txtBoxes, radioButtons, cmboBoxes and even a numericUpDown.  These values have to be stored, so it is my assumption that a List< >  would better suit this than an Array since we don't know how many 'items'  we'll be entering.  I plan to implement Lists< > for each of the fields.
I want to..fill out the form, click Enter Next, which  all fields but stores their values and then clears all fields. Fill out form again x amount of times and ultimately display all.. but I'm missing something in my logic I can't point out.
But what's hanging me up now is an error on 'Name' in my foreach loop. It says that it's a local variable and that it can't use it here, that it will change its' meaning elsewhere in the Parent/Current scope.  But that's why I declared it as a field, assuming that all calls to the variable could use it.   I also searched here, and found [Question about List scope in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280695/question-about-list-scope-in-c-sharp) , but am unsure of how to apply it.
The following code is from my 1st txtBox. Please do excuse my excessive commenting. This is me 'sketching' , making reminders for myself.  I know this question's easy, I'm just failing to see it..

```
namespace Employees
{
    public partial class Employees : Form
    {
        public Employees()
        {       //field declarations.
            string Name;        //'declared but never used?'
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtInputName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { //#1.) *********************************
            Name = txtInputName.Text;
            List<string> InputNameList = new List<string>();
            //InputNameList.Add(Name); 
            //List for holding name input from txtInputName.Text
            //will need ForLoop for consecutive entries. 


            for (int index = 0; index < InputNameList.Count; index++)
            {
                InputNameList.Add(Name);    //but, it's used here.
                MessageBox.Show("success");//Fill List
                txtInputName.Clear();
                txtInputName.Focus();
            } //endFor 


            //for (int index = 0; index < InputNameList.Count; index++); //Display List
            //{             
            //    lstBoxOut.Items.Add(Name);
            //} //displays as before.

            foreach(string Name in InputNameList)   //error on thisName.
            {              
             lstBoxOut.Items.Add(Name);            
            }   //end ForEach
        }      //end txtInputName
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the list itself, and everything to do with the `Name` variable.

You're declaring it as a local variable in the constructor, but never using it. You're then trying to use it at the start of `txtInputName_TextChanged` without declaring it. You're then declaring it again in the `foreach` loop.

I'd suggest:

- Changing all your variable names to follow .NET naming conventions to start with
- Removing the pointless declaration in the constructor
- Changing the start of the method to declare the variable:

  ```
  string name = txtInputName.Text;
  ```
- Changing the foreach loop to declare a *different* variable:

  ```
  foreach (string listName in inputNameList)
  ```

Next you need to work out what your `for` loop in the middle is actually meant to do. If the list is empty to start with, it does nothing. If it's *not* empty to start with, the loop will go on forever.